# How can I align columns vertically in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print(f'{"Progress":2} {"Trailer":3} {"Retriver":4} {"Excluded":5}')
print(f'{"*":2} {"*":3} {"*":4} {"*":5}')
```

The print function prints it as:

```
Progress Trailer Retriver Excluded
*  *   *    *
```

How can I align the star signs under the right column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change align columns vertically in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57156557/how-can-i-change-align-columns-vertically-in-python)

Comment: What did you expect `{"Progress":2}` to do?

Comment: I believe that the number after the string is the width *including* the text so just make sure that the width is bigger than the text length or it messes up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code, it will assign fixed column width and center the words:

```
print(f'{"Progress":^10} {"Trailer":^10} {"Retriver":^10} {"Excluded":^10}')
print(f'{"*":^10} {"*":^10} {"*":^10} {"*":^10}')
```

It will give output as below:

```
 Progress   Trailer    Retriver   Excluded 
    *          *          *          *
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the column widths:

```
print(f'{"Progress":<20} {"Trailer":<20} {"Retriver":<20} {"Excluded":<20}')
print(f'{"*":<20} {"*":<20} {"*":<20} {"*":<20}')
```

###### Output:

```
Progress             Trailer              Retriver             Excluded            
*                    *                    *                    *
```

If you would like to right-align instead, change the `<20` to `>20`